# Fine grain control of AWS S3 object expiration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a task to control object lifecycle of particular objects in S3 bucket. Eg: most of the objects should expire and be deleted according to lifecycle policy, but for some objects I want the expiration never happen. In Amazon SQS there is a possibility to control lifecycle parameters of each single message, but I can't find such feature in docs for S3. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't.  Lifecycle policies apply to all the objects in the bucket, or all the objects with a matching prefix.  You'd need to set the policy on a specific key prefix, and then store the objects you want to match the policy, using that prefix, but the other objects with a different prefix.  That's the closest thing available, and it's not really all that close.

Comment: it's a shame. Thx anyway.